# Pandas really slow join

Tags: python, join, dictionary, pandas

I am trying to merge 2 dataframes, where I want to use the most recent date's row. Note that the date is not sorted, so it is not possible to use `groupby.first()` or `groupby.last()`.

```
Left DataFrame  (n=834,570)     |         Right DataFrame (n=1,592,005)
id_key                          |         id_key    date           other_vars
  1                             |           1       2015-07-06        ...
  2                             |           1       2015-07-07        ...
  3                             |           1       2014-04-04        ...
```

Using the `groupby`/`agg` example, it takes 8 minutes! When I convert the dates to integers, then it takes 6 minutes.

```
gb = right.groupby('id_key')
gb.agg(lambda x: x.iloc[x.date.argmax()])
```

I used my own version where I make a dictionary for id, where I store the date and index of the currently highest date seen. You just iterate over the whole data once, ending up with a dictionary `{id_key : [highest_date, index]}`.

This way, it is really fast to just find the rows necessary.

It only takes 6 seconds to end up with the merged data; about a 85 times speedup.

I have to admit I'm very surprised as I thought pandas would be optimised for this. Does anyone have an idea what is going on, and whether the dictionary method should also be an option in pandas? It would also be simply to adapt this to other conditions of course, like `sum`, `min` etc.

My code:

```
# 1. Create dictionary
dc = {}
for ind, (ik, d) in enumerate(zip(right['id_key'], right['date'])):
    if ik not in dc:
        dc[ik] = (d, ind)
        continue
    if (d, ind) > dc[ik]:
        dc[ik] = (d, ind)

# 2. Collecting indices at once (subsetting was slow), so to only subset once.
# It has the same amount of rows as left
inds = []
for x in left['id_key']: 
    # using this to append the last value that was given (missing strategy, very very few)
    if x in dc:
        row = dc[x][1]
    inds.append(row) 

# 3. Take the values
result = right.iloc[inds]
```